# Converting regular HTML/Javascript to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This might be a general question, but there are a number of projects where existing, bloated frontend needs to be moved to React. There might be effects, styles, animations, forms, and since React does things differently, what are the best practices to reuse what you have for:

- HTML
- CSS
- Javascript

For example I see that [Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) is completely being rewritten for React so there's not much reuse happening there.

Comment: Just out of interest, what are you looking to use with React that you're having difficulty with? The question is rather ambiguous.. Bad design approach is a bad design approach.. Don't have a bad design approach.

Comment: It's not about the design, it's about reusing front end things and converting them to React. It's not a project from scratch, there is quite a lot of front end code already working nicely. But now needs to move to React as is. So, the problem is not in design, but moving existing project to Rect. I would like to know if there are some easy ways or do I have to start from 0, search for similar React components and building what I can't find. Or can I take existing stuff, and semi-automatically convert to React.

Comment: Don't use React the way you currently use Javascript.. Why would you bother 'Migrating' if you did the exact same thing, just differently ?

Comment: I still didn't manage to explain properly. The whole tech stack is moving for various reasons, front and back, and it's beyond my scope of decision making. BUT, the look and feel, and how the front end functions, HAS to stay the same. So I'm looking for easier options rather than rewrite the whole thing in React, I'd rather reuse whatever is reusable.

Comment: -> I don't envy your task.. But you're going to end up re-writing so much you might as-well start from scratch.. At the very least, things will progress smoother.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume that is not trivial task to migrate from one to another. If you projects are simple like some HTML/CSS page than it might be. In another case it is hard to say possible it or not.

About effects, animations: my suggestion is to avoid it without necessity. Or you have to track animation time and make some delaying of calling render() method in React.

Forms data can be easily collected within a fulfilled form state and then pass it to somewhere else (back-end or another state).

The JavaScript logic is hardest part due to the incompatibility of basic React principles. Try to look into something like Flux.

Comment: Well if a designer says there has to be an animation, to point the user to somewhere, then I can't say no. The design team also uses some HTML/CSS/JS generators so that's a another hassle.

Comment: I can give you an example of my point of view:
some times one animation happens and NOT finished, another animation can be triggered. In a result you will get suddenly interrupted first animation and started new one.

Answer (score 0):

React mainly deals with components.React components implement a render() method that takes input data and returns what to display.

You need to divide your html part into different components (just like slicing).It's very different from other projects like php etc. All the functionality mainly depends states and props.

You can re-use your existing css in your project other than bootstrap part.

If you'r interested to convert it into React i think you should start from scratch.I think it's the best option.